# Hive start of week on Sunday?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to get the start of the week (Sundays, as a date) for a given date.  This works except on Sundays since the day of the week origin begins on Monday:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')), CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'u') AS INT))
```

The function above would return '2018-04-15' for a supplied date of '2018-04-22' whereas I want '2018-04-22'.  Is the only recourse to write an case statement to offset for Sundays?  I was hoping there was a nice parameter to FROM_UNIXTIME() that would have the weeks start on Sundays.  I didn't find them in these docs:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the result with a simple trick without case statements.

Calculate the modulus value of the weekday with 7 and you should get your result.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'u')%7 AS INT));
```